Multi curl issue for more than 100k records
I have a requirement to set tax rates for all combinations of US-based states, cities, and zip codes in Magento. There are a total of 130,000 records, and this task needs to be done twice a year. To accomplish this, I have implemented a solution using RabbitMQ. I have created a cron job that publishes the data to a consumer. The cron job processes the data in batches of 500 and sends it to the consumer.
The consumer receives the data and performs the necessary logic. It loops through each record and uses curl_multi_init to make requests to the provided URLs. Based on the response from the curl requests, the data is saved in a table.
Problem : In the consumer, I am facing an issue with the curl requests. When I have a small number of records, such as 8, I am able to retrieve the curl status and response correctly. However, when I increase the number of records to more than 10, the responses become inconsistent. Sometimes I receive empty responses, and other times I do get the expected data.
The problem becomes more pronounced when the number of records exceeds 15. In such cases, the responses are always empty, and the curl status is consistently 0.
Solution : I have attempted to resolve the issue by using standard PHP code, but unfortunately, the problem persists. I am still encountering inconsistent responses with the curl requests, regardless of the approach I take.
I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue. Additionally, if you have any other suggestions or alternative solutions for my requirement, I am open to considering them.
Note : Please ignore object manager. Currently this is in development phase.
Code of my consumer :
private function getTransactionCallback(QueueInterface $queue)
    {
        return function (EnvelopeInterface $message) use ($queue) {
            /** @var LockInterface $lock */
            $lock = null;
            try {
                $lock = $this->messageController->lock($message, $this->configuration->getConsumerName());
                $body = $message->getBody();
                
                $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/consumer.log');
                $logger = new \Zend_Log();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
        
                try{
                    $logger->info('Start');
                    $start = microtime(true);
                    $body = json_decode(json_decode($body, true),true);
                    $mh = curl_multi_init();
                    $handles = [];
                    $associatedData = [];
                    
                    foreach ($body as $key => $msg) {
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        $handles[] = $ch;
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$msg['endpoints']);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

                        $associatedData[(int)$ch] = $msg['entity_id'];

                        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);

                    }

                    $running = null;
                    do {
                        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
                    } while ($running);

                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $sql = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                    $connection = $sql->getConnection();
                    $tableName = $sql->getTableName('us_tax');
                    foreach($handles as $ch){
                        $result = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
                        $rate = 0;
                       
                        try {
                            $id = (int)$ch;
                            $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                            $logger->info('ID : '.$associatedData[$id]);
                            $logger->info('Rate : '.$result);
                            $logger->info(print_r($status,true));
                            if( $result ){
                                $dd = json_decode($result,true);
                                $rate = ((float)json_decode(json_decode($dd))) * 100;     
                            }

                            $connection->update($tableName,['tax_rate' => $rate],['entity_id = ?' => $associatedData[$id]]);

                        }catch(\Exception $e){
                            $logger->info('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
                        }

                        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);

                    }

                    curl_multi_close($mh);
                    $end = microtime(true);
                    $time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);
                    $logger->info('Time execute : '.$time);
                    $logger->info('End');

                }catch (\Exception $e){
                    $logger->info('Error : '.$e->getMessage());

                }

                $data = true;
                if ($data === false) {
                    $queue->reject($message); // if get error in message process
                }
                $queue->acknowledge($message); // send acknowledge to queue 
            } catch (MessageLockException $exception) {
                $queue->acknowledge($message);
            } catch (ConnectionLostException $e) {
                $queue->acknowledge($message);
                if ($lock) {
                    $this->resource->getConnection()
                        ->delete($this->resource->getTableName('queue_lock'), ['id = ?' => $lock->getId()]);
                }
            } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
                $queue->acknowledge($message);
                $this->logger->warning($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $queue->reject($message, false, $e->getMessage());
                $queue->acknowledge($message);
                if ($lock) {
                    $this->resource->getConnection()
                        ->delete($this->resource->getTableName('queue_lock'), ['id = ?' => $lock->getId()]);
                }
            }
        };
    }


If you are hitting the same endpoint - is there some form of rate limiting at their end?

@NigelRen - We are not sure on this point. We have connected with the team for the same and they are said they have not added any rate limit

you are looping continuous without any pause which would initially  break the script . try sleep after few loop and try.

@AbhishekKumar - Thanks Abhishek. Let me try

also check for max_execution_time  in you php.ini file  set it to 0 for unlimited time.

also if possible try to send multiple request in single curl  request if your other server can process multiple records at once.

@AbhishekKumar - max_execution_time = 0 is not a good approach in my opinion. Every curl request has its own params and it needs to be call every time.

you mean this would be 500 curl request in each job . so the thing is the request is sent to fast  in loop that the remote server firewall or any other dos protection system would  block the request in assumption as a dos attack . the same thing happened with us when we implemented same sort of thing. make sure the remote server is not blocking your request as Dos attack.

@AbhishekKumar - Yes that's one of the concern we do have now. What you have done to resolve this issue?

you have to provide some info so that we can help.  1)  the remote server is owned by you or not ? 2) the request made is authorized or just some scrapper ? 3) if you could provide the records data and what exact request you made through curl ?

if its possible you can group records and minimize no of  quest made by combining them into one

Thanks @AbhishekKumar for your help and guidance. This feature has been hold for now in our project.
